# AJAX request to an infinite loop on php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a server that is running and waiting for datas

```
    while(true){
            $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $messageRecieved, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
            ....
            ....
            ....
            $jsonData = array("Name" => $sensor->getName(), "Value" => $sensor->getValue(), "Tipology" => $sensor->getTipology(), "Timestamp" => $sensor->getTimestamp());
            echo json_encode($jsonData);
        }
```

Then i have an Ajax Request to that script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../serverScript.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
            response["Name"] = response["Name"].replace(/\s/g, '');
            divId = $('#' + response["Name"]);
            if (!divId.length){
                $('#serverResult').append('' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-4 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded one marginTop-1" id = "' + response["Name"] + '">' +
                        '<h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">' + response["Name"] + '</h3>' +
                    '</div>'
                );
            }
            $("#"+response["Name"]).append(response["Tipology"] + " " + response["Value"] + " " + response["Timestamp"]);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.warn(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry for the bad code, both Ajax Request and Php script are going to be way better, i just need to make things works first!

My Problem is:

The Ajax Request works perfectly when i remove the while from the server code and do just one iteration of the cycle. The problem is that i would like to have an Ajax Request for every message recieved from the server. So, basically, i need a way to use the Ajax Request inside the while loop.
Anyway to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think talking to a socket on the server via ajax is the right way. You'll need to talk via [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) to the server.

Comment: Each AJAX call is a separate HTTP request that starts a new script. If you want continuous communication with a script in a loop you should look into websockets.

Comment: Does WebSocket support UDP connection instead of TCP?